# AnimationDrawable auto starts

Tags: android, animation, imageview, visibility

I have a problem with an `AnimationDrawable` that I create programatically that starts as soon as I assign it to an `ImageView` via `imageView.setBackgroundDrawable` (I support API 8).

This is an abbreviation of my code:

```
 mSequence = new AnimationDrawable();
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
 ImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
```

All of my assets are saved locally so I add them to the `AnimationDrawable`

```
for(String assetId : mAssets) {
    bitmap = loadBitmap(assetId); // returns a bitmap saved earlier
    if (bitmap != null) {
        mSequence.addFrame(new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap), mFrameDuration);
    }
}
```

And finally I assign the `AnimationDrawable` to the view

```
if (mSequence.getNumberOfFrames() > 0) {
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(mSequence);
}
```

Now before I have a chance to call the `start()` function the animation starts as soon as the `ImageView` is loaded.

I want to be able to control when the animation starts according to my own logic.

Has this happened to anyone?

**

### EDIT:

**

Thanks to Tom, I know the reason for the triggering of the animation is the change in visibility that happens to the `ImageView` that actively happens after assigning the `AnimationDrawable`. The solution in my case isn't trivial since I have a complicated situation but for others it might be simpler.

### EDIT 2:

I'm back to setting the drawable as the background according to [class description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html), and I quote:

> The simplest way to create a frame-by-frame animation is to define the
>   animation in an XML file, placed in the res/drawable/ folder, and set
>   it as the **background** to a View object. Then, call start() to run the
>   animation.

Comment: It's quite possibly because you're assigning it as a background drawable with `setBackgroundDrawable`- when you assign a background drawable via a View it calls setVisible(..) which can trigger an animation. PS: why aren't you able to call `setImageDrawable`?

Comment: take a look at my tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/frame-by-frame-animation/

Comment: @Tom You were right! it is triggered because of a visibility change. It doesn't make sense. Is there a good way to prevent it from happening?
PS: I changed it to `setImageDrawable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possibly because you're assigning it as a background drawable with  `setBackgroundDrawable`- when you assign a background drawable a chain of calls to  super.setVisibility ends up in View, and that `setVisible(..)` can trigger an animation.

The solution is to use ImageDrawable?

[Here's](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@2.0_r1@android%24graphics%24drawable@Drawable@setVisible%28boolean,boolean%29&k=u) how I found the culprit.

As for why it's like that, it's probably a design choice about which I am too ignorant to explain, allthough I can see why- it marks out the difference between being a background and being a picture- the former has a conceptually longer life-span, perhaps. (But that's a geuss).

If you want to use the setting backgrounds approach, perhaps try keeping your `ImageViews` invisible until you want to show the animation.

Comment: I changed the assign method to `setImageDrawable` but still as soon as the imageview becomes visible the animation starts. I don't want that kind of restriction.

Comment: Perhaps you're gonna have to roll your own then. Can you not preload drawables the and then set them actually on the `ImageView` only as needed (i.e. when you want the animation to start)?

Comment: I can, but by saving a reference to the `ImageView` and setting the image when needed, I'm keeping a reference to the `Context` which is something I would like to avoid if possible

Comment: This is very decent analysis- can you use the "Application Context" instead? We have found that Android's implementation of drawables is very patchy at best. We have one or two cases where we've just rolled our own implementations from scratch, you may end up having to do that yourself.

Comment: I am writing an android library and therefore have no way to get the Application Context without demanding it explicitly. Well, at least I know why it happens. I'll try and get creative... :)

Comment: Great. Wish you best of luck indeed! Hope you have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is more than a year old but I will share my experience.

- The simplest way to stop your animation, that I have found, is to do this:

  ```
  mImageView.setImageDrawable(mAnimationDrawable);
  mAnimationDrawable.stop();
  mAnimationDrawable.selectDrawable(0);
  ```

and that's it.

This essentially stops the animation on the drawable at index 0.  It is a workaround, however, but an easy two extra lines is all that is needed.

Comment: I believe its #selectDrawable() instead of #selectFrame(), but this seems like an obvious solution.

Comment: Thank you @milosmns.  Yes `selectDrawable()` is indeed the correct method (edited).  Intuitive/obvious or not it took me a while to come to this conclusion: to stop the animation after setting it using the `setImageDrawable(Drawable)` method requires the two operations `stop()` and `selectDrawable(int)` in that order ( as of Lollipop ).  It's odd that it does not stop after calling the `stop()` method only.

Comment: Seems to be fixing issues of autostarting for G3 ROM as well. Not sure about G2, but it's likely to fix everything there as well

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of the above workarounds fixed the issue here. My solution was to use:

```
myView.setTranslationX(10000f); // to hide
myView.setTranslationX(0f); // to show
```